# Vim enable mouse scroll only - not cursor positioning

Tags: vim, xterm

I want to enable the mouse wheel for scrolling like `^e` and `^y` do. I don't want clicking in a buffer to move the cursor though, so `:set mouse=a` does not help me.

Reason is that I have a bunch of gui windows open (web browser, chat etc) and click to focus vim, but if I click inside the buffer it moves the cursor to where I clicked. I also like to use the mouse wheel for scrolling because I find it faster than `^e` and `^y`, and easier to keep track if where I am that `^d` and `^u` or `<pgdn>` and `<pgup>`.

Is there a way to enable the mouse support for scrolling, but disable cursor position change when clicking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can selectively disable mouse buttons by mapping them to `<nop>`. For example, to disable the left mouse button:

```
:nmap <LeftMouse> <nop>
:imap <LeftMouse> <nop>
:vmap <LeftMouse> <nop>
```

If you also want to ignore double clicks:

```
:nmap <2-LeftMouse> <nop>
…
```

See:

```
:help gui-mouse-mapping
:help map-overview
```

Comment: Great, just what I was looking for. Any chance it could still allow window/tab selection though (without changing cursor position)?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do that, but I won't say it can't be done.